# cursorAdapter filter listview by two criteria

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview and it's populated by product label and Code,which comes from database,

i want to filter listview by these "label" and "code" values(double filtering) but i dont know how to do it.
And there is working no filter,after i type 3 characters all list shown below.

Anyone help?

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView lv;
    EditText searchBox;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Database db = Database.getDatabase();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edSearch);

   lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   displayListView();
   }

  private void displayListView() {

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getDatabaseEntityOperations().fetchEntities(
            searchBox);


    String[] columns = new String[] 
       {
            myDb.getDatabaseEntityOperations().entity_Code,
            myDb.getDatabaseEntityOperations().entity_Label };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] boundTo = new int[] { R.id.product_code, R.id.product_label };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    // as well as the layout information

            cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.single_search_item, cursor, columns,boundTo,0);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
           lv.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the
            // result set

            Cursor cursor=cursorAdapter.getCursor();

            String pass_data_label = cursor.getString(4).toString();
            String pass_data_code= cursor.getString(3).toString();


            Intent intent = (new     Intent(MainActivity.this,ProductInfo.class));              
            intent.putExtra("label",pass_data_label);
            intent.putExtra("code",pass_data_code);

            startActivity(intent);
            // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.

        }
    });

    searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            if (searchBox.length() >= 3) {
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (searchBox.length() < 3) {
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }

    });

    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            return myDb.getDatabaseEntityOperations().fetchEntities(
                    searchBox);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: FilterQueryProvider#runQuery "filters out" your db so make it return different Cursors depending on some condition

Comment: i comment out setFilterQueryProvider() method and still there is no filter,i think at least one filter should work.i couldnt find where was i wrong? @pskink

Comment: you have to use  setFilterQueryProvider(), just use FilterQueryProvider that has an "if" statement returning 2 different Cursors depending on some criteria

Comment: i changed it like you said but i still dont know where should i call this method and this methods returning cursor is an sql statement "select * from entity_table",is this make any problem? @pskink

Comment: place a breakpoint inside runQuery(),  debug your app and see how it works